# How to generate .phar in netbeans

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem of building the php appliction.

**Target 'build' does not exist in this project**

in netbeans php project.

Just send what are all the prosedures to build a phar along with composer in netbeans IDE using ubuntu os

Comment: please add more specific details!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans has plugins, you can install [NBPhar](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/58816/nbphar), which will help you to create `.phar` file.

---

You can create `.phar` file by following below steps :

Create a new PHP file named create-phar.php in your myapp root with the following code:

```
<?php
$srcRoot = "~/myapp/src";
$buildRoot = "~/myapp/build";

$phar = new Phar($buildRoot . "/myapp.phar", 
    FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO |       FilesystemIterator::KEY_AS_FILENAME, "myapp.phar");
$phar["index.php"] = file_get_contents($srcRoot . "/index.php");
$phar["common.php"] = file_get_contents($srcRoot . "/common.php");
$phar->setStub($phar->createDefaultStub("index.php"));

copy($srcRoot . "/config.ini", $buildRoot . "/config.ini");
```

Then open a terminal window, navigate to the myapp directory and run it:

```
$ php create-phar.php
```

Refer this article [Packaging Your Apps with Phar](https://www.sitepoint.com/packaging-your-apps-with-phar/) for detailed explanation.

Comment: I have tried this option but the project has problem in building the application. It shows that "Target 'build' does not exist in this project". error on building the project.

Comment: just send me demo project along with generating phars

Comment: yeah i tried this link.. after i got a problem on building the application

Comment: I don't have setup with me. Let me check, if I get anything.

Comment: @srinivasan I have updated the post. I have no setup with me. So, I'm not sure. But, I'm pretty sure. This will work for you.

Comment: Thank you for spending your time for me.

Comment: @srinivasan better you should post another question with your code, which you tried and post complete folder structure and complete error you are getting.

Comment: first i have create a "index.php"

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>index</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
require_once "phar://myapp.phar/common.php";
$config = parse_ini_file("config.ini");
AppManager::run($config);
  
        ?>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: @srinivasan No. You should post it as question.

Comment: In Netbeans IDE how to build and generate a phar file in php project along with phing and composer.  As if i got trouble on building and generating phar file.

Comment: @srinivasan Any specific reason to build using Netbeans ?? If you got alternative to do same thing, then why are you stick to one point. You should always make things simple and easy. Do not waste time on one specific thing until that is the only way to do.

Comment: @srinivasan Now,  as I mentioned, try what I have posted, if you are not getting it then, you need to post complete details of what you tried and the error. That will help us to identify the actual cause.

Comment: i want some more clarification regarding this

Comment: Bro i got an answer for generating phar using phar-composer:                    1.install composer that is followed by composer.org website.                       2.download php.composer.phar file in website ans install it , make the  access with the root.                                                                                      3.After completing all the coding and composer packages, go to terminal and phar-composer ~/path of your project